# How do i add custom theme from bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using this theme https://themes.getbootstrap.com/product/purpose-website-ui-kit/

For some reason, I can't make it to work on my rails project, it's a bit confusing should I install the bootstrap gem or add it to package.json

This is the assets that I got from the theme

[image]

There's a folder called assets on my rails project, I'm guessing this where I supposed to dump all my css and images files?

[image]

This is where things get confusing, there's another folder called javascript with a stylesheets folder.

[image]

How do I properly configure the custom Bootstrap theme on my newly Rails project?

Comment: I've only barely used Rails, but does this look helpful to you? https://medium.com/@chan0123/integrate-custom-bootstrap-theme-in-rails-9e78070e6ba I think you have to install some gems to make it work.